# Possible categorizations using recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have two arrays, one contains top-level categories and another contains sub-categories where the length of sub-categories > length of top-level categories.

I'm trying to write a recursive algorithm to give me all the possible ways I can place the sub-categories into the top-level categories.  So, for example, if I have top-level categories `[A,B,C]` and sub-categories `[W,X,Y,Z]` I would get:

```
A->WXYZ, B->null, C->null
A->XYZ,  B->W,    C->null
A->WYZ,  B->X,    C->null
...
A->null, B->Z,    C->WXY
A->null, B->null, C->WXYZ
```

At first glance, I don't think this problem can be solved with a typical permutation algorithm, but I could be wrong; I'm not too good with recursion.

Thanks!

Comment: So, each subcategory should be in at most one category? Or exactly one?

Comment: Each subcategory should be in exactly one category.

Comment: I think i can find a recursive solution, but it uses too much memory, do you need a practical implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need permutations and you don't need recursion, you just need to count. Say you have N categories and M subcategories - you need to go over all the M-digit numbers in base N.

Let's take your 3 categories, but call them 0, 1 and 2 - that is, all the digits in base-3. Now let's look at all the 4 digit numbers in base 3:

0000, 0001, 0002, 0010, 0011, 0012, ... , 2212, 2220, 2221, 2222

Each number represents an allocation of subcategories to categories, like so - the first digit is for subcategory W, the second for subcategory X, the third for subcategory Y and the last is for subcategory Z.

So, 0000 means WXYZ are in the first category (your first line in the example). 1000 is your second line, 2222 is your last line, and so on.

Comment: +1 for Awesome parallel to counting.

It's hard to realize this because the way the requirement was designed. If he had instead described it as: Each of M subcategories needs to fall into exactly 1 of N categories, and created a map from subcategories to categories in his explanation, OP would have probably seen this.

Awesome find.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a permutation problem like you thought.

You have N subcategories that need to be put in M categories. This is very similar to the [stars and bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

I could write some code, but I think it would be good for you to do a reading.

Comment: This looks like the approach I need to take.  I'll try and code it up and post a solution. Thanks!

Comment: On further review, I don't think this approach will work. It seems the stars and bars only works when *"one distinguishes the bins ... but one does not wish to distinguish the k stars"*. In my scenario, the "stars" (being subcategories) are distinguishable.